# Add supported app at runtime in Selendroid

Tags: java, selenium, testing, selendroid

I'm using the code as from the Selendroid [quickstart](http://selendroid.io/quickStart.html) tutorial (pasted below) to launch the selendroid-standalone application.

```
SelendroidConfiguration config = new SelendroidConfiguration();
// Add the selendroid-test-app to the standalone server
config.addSupportedApp("src/main/resources/selendroid-test-app-0.15.0.apk");
selendroidServer = new SelendroidLauncher(config);
selendroidServer.launchSelendroid();
```

Now, since I want to test multiple applications which I don't know a priori, I'd like to leave the standalone executing and adding new supported applications at runtime. I could not find anything related to this in the documentation, except from a command-line option `-folder` which is said to specify a directory to monitor for new *.apk* files to sign and support.

It is close to what I want, but not exactly. I'd like to be able to individually pick supported apps to add via Java APIs to the standalone. I'd rather avoid havin to create a folder and copy the *.apk* in there from the code. Can I keep invoking `config.addSupportedApp` even after the `selendroidServer` has been launched, in example? I could not find any proper documentation for that method.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually not possible to add apps at the runtime to the `selendroid` server. One thing you can do though is that you can stop the current server instance and then start the new server right from your code. You can try to implement that. This is all I can suggest as an alternative.

Comment: I could also invoke the commandline instead, and supply the `-folder` option I mentioned. That would do. I can't restart the server because there might be other tests running on a different emulator when I want to add another supported app.